# cmd - Copy only new files / folders on Windows

Tags: cmd, file-transfer, robocopy, xcopy

I am doing a class right now that has us do a `git pull` at the beginning of each class to pull down any new files that might have been added to the class repo. I can't make changes to the class repo folder for obvious reasons, so I need to copy the newly added folders to my active folder. the two folders are identical except the active folder has all of my changes and completed homework assignments.

I already created a `.cmd` file that does the `git pull` for me. It was super easy; barely an inconvenience. But I would like to also have it copy any new files from the class repo to the active folder.

I was looking at documentation and I found three maybe options, but I don't really know how to actually use any of them correctly to make sure they don't overwrite my homework. There is `copy`, `Xcopy`, and `robocopy`. I created a super simple file tree just to test these, but they keep overwriting the destination folder.

In `Xcopy`, there is an option that reads:

> `/U    Copy only files that already exist in destination.`

I want it to do the opposite of this. I want it to copy only files that do NOT already exist in destination.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `xcopy /?` and read the output help. Best would be using option `/M`. On first execution is copied everything. On all further executions are copied only the files on which Windows set again the archive file attribute which is done automatically by Windows on a file modified, created or renamed in the source directory. I recommend to run in command prompt window `robocopy /?` and read about this command replacing older `xcopy` since Windows Vista. `%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe` is even more powerful than `xcopy.exe`.

Comment: I think that worked. Thank you. I still don't understand what archive does but I think it's working so I'm happy.